# ¿Existe alguna forma de iterar sobre una BBDD MySQL con PHP sin llevarte los datos a un array primero?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Básicamente quiero recorrer todos los datos de una tabla de una BBDD MySQL, para luego comparar registro a registro con los datos existentes en otra tabla de la misma BBDD, y ver cuándo unos datos se han modificado y cuándo no (para cuándo los datos de la tabla1 sean distintos a los de la tabla2, actualizar la tabla2). Por tanto, tengo dos opciones: o recorro la tabla MySQL directamente (que no sé si puede) o uso arrays para ello (sacando todos los datos de la tabla a un array). La pregunta es...¿se puede recorrer una tabla MySQL directamente o tengo que utilizar arrays sí o sí? Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Se puede recorrer los datos directamente, dentro del `while` que uses para leer los resultados. Aunque si quieres hacer comparaciones con otra base de datos, a mi juicio, sería más problemático hacerlo con dos conexiones abiertas al mismo tiempo.  El motivo es que los resultados son devueltos como recursos, y las dos conexiones tendrían que estar abiertas en paralelo. Esto tendría una mayor demanda en el sistema que guardar un array, cerrar la primera conexión, abrir la segunda conexión, y comparar los datos de ella con el array anterior. Así tendrías una sola conexión abierta a la vez.

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: También, si las dos bases de datos son del mismo SGBD/servidor podrías armar una sola consulta que haga las comparaciones entre tablas, usando `JOIN` y demás. Entre dos BD o más BD del msmo SGBD/servidor es posible hacer algo como: `SELECT ...  FROM bd1.unaTablaEnBD1  INNER JOIN bd2.unaTablaEnBD2 ON ... `

Comment: ¿Y esa sentencia JOIN puede ir haciendo consultas automáticamente a fin de ir sincronizándote las tablas de forma automática?

Comment: La palabra correcta no sería *sincronizar* en este caso. Tú podrías armar una consulta que te actualice una determinada tabla en base a ella. Como digo de un `SELECT` parecido al indicado más arriba, puedes armar también una consulta del tipo `UPDATE` o del tipo `INSERT` o del tipo `DELETE` que en base a unos criterios te actualice, inserte o borre unos determinados registros. Pero OJO: esto sería una *normalización*  más que una *sincronización* y sería algo que harías **para regularizar alguna situación inicial anómala**. Una vez normalizado, tendrías que usar otras herramientas ...

Comment: ... más adecuadas. Como sería el uso de restricciones de *integridad referencial*, o el uso de disparadores (`TRIGGER`)  o el uso de eventos. Son herramientas que asegurarían la *normalidad*  de tus tablas **de forma automática**, sin necesidad de tu intervención. Es importante que tengas clara la diferencia entre *normalizar*  y *sincronizar*. Generalmente, en un mismo servidor la sincronización no tendría sentido. La sincronización suele tener sentido cuando tienes datos en dos lugares diferentes.

Comment: Entiendo que normalizar sería como poner ambas tablas a punto (es decir, si en una tabla hay distinto nº de registros, y con distintos campos, poner ambas tablas con mismo nº de registros y de campos) y que sincronizar hacer que cuando ocurra un cambio en una, se haga en otra de forma automática. ¿Estoy en lo correcto? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Sí. Pero *sincronizar* no tendría mucho sentido si las BD están en el mismo servidor. Generalmente se sincroniza entre un servidor y un cliente (una base de datos remota por ejemplo y en dispositivo local), o entre una base de datos remota y una aplicación móvil. La normalización entre dos bases de datos, sería algo puntual, por ejemplo con el objetivo de quedarte usando una sola base de datos definitiva entre las dos, una vez todo haya sido normalizado.

Comment: ¿Por qué no tiene sentido sincronizar dos BD en el mismo servidor? Porque es justo lo que me están pidiendo a mí. Supongo que es porque en ese caso sobra una de las tablas, ¿no?

Comment: Porque no tiene ningún sentido tener duplicidad de datos, tener dos veces una misma BD en dos sitios es eso: duplicidad de datos... con todo el trabajo añadido que supondría tenerlas sincronizadas. Si la idea es tener los datos asegurados por si una de las BD se daña, entonces lo propio es implementar una política de copia de seguridad.

Comment: Pues tienes toda la razón del mundo. Muchas gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tendrás que recurrir a la utilización de arrays.

No obstante, si el problema es tan solo lo que planteas en tu pregunta (recorrer la tabla1, comparar con la tabla2 y en caso de que tengan valores distintos en las filas, actualizar la tabla), puedes hacerlo sin necesidad de recurrir a PHP. Concretamente podrías hacerte un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL (SP) y realizar en el mismo la lógica que comentas en tu post.

Comment: Se puede, pero me piden implementarlo con PHP. Muchas gracias.